# How to detect compile errors in resources fetched by Drools KnowledgeAgent setup with Spring

Tags: spring, drools

I have setup a Drools-Spring project where I use KnowledgeAgent to poll for changes in the resources. It's working fine up to a point when there's a (compile) error in one of the rule files, in which case it just silently fails.

[Discussions elsewhere](http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Creating-a-KnowledgeBase-using-a-KnowledgeAgent-KnowledgeAgentConfiguration-and-KnowledgeBaseConfigun-td1286467.html#a1791917) suggest that one should add a [`KnowledgeAgentEventListener`](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/knowledge-api-javadoc/org/drools/event/knowledgeagent/KnowledgeAgentEventListener.html) in order to get compile errors. I just cannot find a proper way of setting **this listener** with Spring XML configuration. There are options for WorkingMemoryListener,  AgendaListener and  ProcessEventListener as stated in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.CR5/droolsjbpm-integration-docs/html/ch.spring.html#d0e499), but none seems to react on compile errors (my assumptions are based on the documentation)

Is there such a possibility currently with Drools-Spring integration? To which element and with what syntax should the listener be added?

Thanks.

Comment: In 5.5, package org.drools.event.knowledgeagent had class ResourceCompilationFailedEvent in the stable (!) API, but in 6.0.0 the class has slinked away into some kie.internal package. I'd say, this doesn't look as if this feature were supported in Spring. - Anyway, installing a DRL without a previous offline check is a bit cheeky, IMHO.

Comment: @laune, I see. The reason I'm doing this is that I'm in a search for a lightweight rules repository, an alternative to Guvnor and Workbench. Any suggestions?